# Transistors: P-Type/N-Type circuit with high-school electronics knowledge

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-analysis

I am studying about transistors, and I have only high school knowledge about circuits.

I don't understand this figure:

[image]

- How is this circuit closed?
- What is the little triangle?
- How do 1.2V and the little triangle close a circuit?
- How do the input and output close the circuit?

Comment: Hi LeoC! Sorry, but if you want to understand schematics with transistors, high school electronics will not suffice; right now you're just confused about a symbol, but you will need a whole lot of circuit theory to actually understand what a transistor *does*, leave alone *how* it does... The triangle is a symbol for "ground", which we canonically use as reference to which to understand any voltage in a diagram (that's why there's "0 volts" written next to it).

Comment: Also, LeoC, if the ground symbol is new to you, then it might not be a good idea to start with material that explains something as complicated as a CMOS pair. For example, it's really important that you understand what a MOSFET is before you start tackling this question. It would answer your first, your third and your fourth question. Sorry, but you're trying to skip too many basics, and you **can't** understand what's happening here without us explaining a whole book that you should read before. This makes your question too broad to be answered :(

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, thanks for the edit. OPs don't usually seem to pay attention to edits thus why I commented.

Comment: @LeoC - I was in middle school when I started on this stuff. Hopefully you'll have a lifelong interest, if not a career in it.

Answer (score 3):

What's shown is a CMOS inverter constructed from Metallic Oxide Semiconductor Field Effect Transistors (MOSFETs) running at 1.2V. MOSFETs are **voltage-controlled devices** that can be used as switches to make logic. [Read more about MOSFETS here](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_6.html).

As you observed, like bipolar transistors, MOSFETs (we'll call them just FETs from here on) come in 'p-type' and 'n-type'. Both types are used here to make a simple inverter.

Diagram (a) shows the upper p-FET with a bubble on the gate, the lower n-FET is indicated by no bubble. That bubble/no-bubble style is short-hand notation for logic FETs: the gate bubble (p-FET) indicates 'low' is on, while no-bubble (n-FET) means 'high' is on.

The power connections are 1.2V at top, and 0V at the 'triangle' at bottom. We'll revisit what those mean below. For now, treat these as if they are connections to a 1.2V battery (+) for "1.2 Volts" and (-) for the 'triangle'.

Diagram (b) shows the switching action:

- input low: upper p-FET 'on', lower n-FET 'off' => output high (connected to 1.2V)

And we also know that:

- input high: lower n-FET is 'on', upper p-FET 'off' => output low (connected to 0V).

How does the inverter work? **The FETs are acting like switches, controlled by their gate voltage**. And the neat part is, since they switch with opposite voltages, **only one FET is on at a time** when connected this way. The pair of FETs act like a **voltage-controlled single-pole double-throw switch**.

Rather than try to further explain it to death in words, let's build a simulation to see what this inverter actually does. ([try it here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEAmA7NVbnIBwBYFkBmMIogThxAQDZrrJqBTAWjDACgAzFSKsVHSzhBKCDCoxIybryrCFmXlGiTYMgO4olYcsm37seKBy0LkxhbRNm%20IoXaM25KCy%20GQOAWRBF8r4zwwITdGGBoOACUDcBpGYXZ9MJA8RjBoJKgVBA4AcxjceSUiZGTNX38nMhDjTy1qgILQjgAnXyI6ATo-Yy6ssHhTdprh%20xNonrGgztFk1JU6ZJgc%20o7GhuRrOtHN7sqtjg6qSd2U4JQt8fc3MFxGuaWs5Y4AD2pDIjTIJGIiFJRjABJAB2AAcAK4AF1eKTw5Fc8MI8RK-zcAHkoRDoQB7EQgGi1FKQcjwqTwQTIcgUAgkTYqeDEwS0OlpEAgrEAHQAzgA1bEAG0hAENckwOLi6ASsqlKOAMkgYBAlYd%20KgQAAxcT9DIgNhssFQ7l8wUisVAA)):

[image]

Now, a bit of detail about the sim:

- The FETs have a *threshold voltage* set to 0.8V. I'll explain why this matters below.
- I added a load resistor to the output to show how current flows in each FET.
- The 'triangle' symbol is *Ground*, or 0V (often abbreviated as GND).

Let's talk about Ground for a moment. Common Ground symbols you'll find in electronic schematics include these:

[image]

The most common GND styles used are the left-most 'Earth' (for Power) and the middle 'Signal' shapes. In your case they've used the 'Signal'. Still, they all just mean zero volts.

There's another shorthand they've used here. When you see a labeled voltage (e.g., "1.2 Volts" shown at top) there is an **implied power supply which is referenced to GND**.

You can think of the "1.2 Volts" label as the wire to the (+) side of a 1.2V battery, with its (-) terminal connected to GND.

We can also show such a battery explicitly, like this ([simulate it here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEAmA7NVbnIBwBYFkBmMIogThxADYk7IQEBTAWjDACgAzFSKsVNRSZwglBBhUYkZN15Usw5Et5RoU2LIDuKsOWWLseKBx2HkxwwiGRT80UOR8UFk2edH7i2wFkQRfBdjPDBHVwYYajsAy1cyMONbHXiglU9bACd-IiEBIRiHKHB4aJzUlLyTACV-QMqQ3LEIkDwI6BsimARShOzHazc%20lAGC5AHbHIURMFwVcg7bGqcFVxmVxKLWzs7oboAPEHIGJ1RwPCJxBktjAEkAOwAHAFcAFw4DvDxyF2-CY6JlNcQAB5V7PN4ANxAbHyTmhoXAs2aWzA0GUzS6dkUoWO0yRWLxVBhiKkdmJANxygpg0U1MMOFJBzYkFO2AuLHOLiExhm4DRADUADoAZwAQgBDF4vJgZACeHAA5vDYQxyWUIhxJrVLAMGsMFhwAPbgJDUDatcjfaTwQTIcgUAgkMZqeCQciCazOhgQe7gkX8w0AGxe4oVTCNNBo5rd-DRSBgEETmv4SAAYhIiqjlGwQL7Xv6gyGwxwgA)):

[image]

Anyway, click the link and try the 'Input Voltage' slider. Here's what the inverter does as the input swings from 0 up to 1.2V:

- Input voltage is low (0V), upper FET is ON and pulls the output high - current flows from 1.2V
- In between 0.4V and 0.8V, both FETs are off - no current flows. This is a Good Thing, as I'll explain below
- Above 0.8V, lower FET turns ON - current flows into GND

What's going on? FETs turn on when they have the correct **gate-to-source voltage** (Vgs). Go back to the sim and hover your mouse over each FET. You'll see labels for the FET pins as 'S', 'G', and 'D'. These are, Source, Gate and Drain. Note the source connections: +1.2V for the p-FET, and GND for the n-FET.

Digging deeper, hover over each FET again. At lower right you'll see some information about the FET. The key thing to note is **Gate-Source voltage**, or **Vgs**. That's what makes the FET turn on.

Looking at each FET then, we see that:

- p-FET is ON when its gate-source voltage is more negative than -0.8V, that is, **the input less than 0.4V**
- n-FET is ON when its gate-source voltage is more than 0.8V, that is, **the input greater than 0.8V**

And what about input voltage in between 0.4V and 0.8V? **That is "no man's land" where both FETs are OFF.** Why is this important? This "no man's land" **ensures that only one FET is on at a time,** so they don't short out the power supply as the input swings from low to high or high to low.

I chose the 0.8V threshold as this is 2/3 of 1.2V. We thus say that this inverter has an *input-low threshold* of 1/3 Vcc (0.4V) and *input-high threshold* of 2/3 Vcc (0.8V). This is pretty typical for CMOS.

If we start to move the thresholds lower - to 0.6V, say - we start to see that both FETs are on during the low-to-high or high-to-low transition time, leading to a current spike in the power supply. You can try this yourself by editing the FETs.

There's lots of other sims you can try in [Falstad](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html), and you can easily make your own. Happy learning!

Answer (score 0):

What the diagram is showing is an inverter using complementary transistors.

For a high or low input one or the other transistor will be on but not both. In this circuit a high input (1) is 1.2 V, low (0) is 0 V. The diagram on the right shows the circuit with a low input, the p-type transistor on top will turn on for a low input but the n-type will not, so the line through the p-type is indictating a closed circuit. This connects the output to 1.2 V, so for a 0 input the output is a 1.

Likewise if the input is a 1 the n-type will conduct and the p-type will not, so the output will be connected to 0 V, a 1 input gives a 0 output. This is a digital inverter and it's truth table is:

In | Out
0  | 1
1  | 0

As was noted in the comments, if all of this is new to you and you don't understand, you should start at a much lower level. Generally you first learn about voltage and current sources, then resistors, then capacitors and inductors, and only then do you start to learn about things like diodes and transistors.

Answer (score 0):

The drawing implies that there is a 1.2 Volt power supply connected between the top line marked "1.2 volts" and the bottom triangle marked "0 volts".  That power supply completes the circuit.

The downward-pointing triangle (and other similar symbols) indicate "Ground" - rarely an actual connection to the earth, but usually just the point in the circuit we want to call "zero volts" and use as a reference when measuring voltage elsewhere in the circuit.

Sample circuits in textbooks, such as this circuit, will often omit parts of the circuit that are not relevant to the topic being discussed.